# Locating whether two instances of an array are in the same position

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to work out a way for my game to recognise when two instances of this array have the same x or y position as another and if so to move re randomize the position of one of the instances.:

```
for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
        PlatformInstance[i] =new Platform();
     PlatformInstance[i].y= Math.random()*900;
     PlatformInstance[i].x= Math.random() *1500;
     stage.addChild(PlatformInstance[i]);

 }
```

the problem i have is that the code i try detects that one platform instance has the same position as the SAME platform instance, and will constantly re randomize the position.
is there a way to differentiate between different instances?

thanks very much in advance.

EDIT

The only code i could think of was running an if statement in a loop to see whether

`If (PlatformInstance[i].y == PlatformInstance[i].y)`

Obviously this wouldnt work and thinking of it i know it wouldn't however i was wondering if there was a way to do:

```
 If (Platforminstance[i].y == "other" Platforminstance[i].y
```

or some other words to that effect

Comment: What code have you tried? Also I think you're referring to "elements in an array", not "instances of an array", correct? Your wording is a bit confusing

Comment: Sorry yes, i do mean elements of the array, the only code i could think of was running an if statement in a loop to see whether PlatformInstance[i].y == PlatformInstance[i].y, obviously this wouldnt work and thinking of it i know it wouldn't however i was wondering if there was a way to do:

Comment: If (Platforminstance[i].y == "other" Platforminstance[i].y

Comment: Edit your question to make it clearer, and put the code you've tried in there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't seem to have a clear understanding of how arrays work, I recommend looking into that. Something like this should work

```
   i=0;
   j=0;
   while( i < PlatformInstance.length -1) {
      j++;
      if (j == PlatformInstance.length) {
         i++;
         j=i+1;
      }

      if( (Math.abs(PlatformInstance[i].x - PlatformInstance[j].x) < platformWidth)
      || (Math.abs(PlatformInstance[i].y - PlatformInstance[j].y) < platformHeight) ) {

         PlatformInstance[j].y= Math.random()*900;
         PlatformInstance[j].x= Math.random() *1500;
         //Now you'll have start checking at the beginning again since you moved one
         i=0;
         j=0;
         continue;
      }
   }
```

Also as it was previously mentioned, `PlatformInstance` is not a good name for an array. Only Class names should start with a capital letter. And an array of platforms should not be called an "instance". I would recommend changing it to simply `platforms`

Comment: Thanks very much, this seems to work to a certain extent, the only problem i have is because the platforms are a decent size, they some times still overlap, is it possible to make the 
      if(PlatformInstance[i].x == PlatformInstance[j].x
      || PlatformInstance[i].y == PlatformInstance[j].y) 
into something which isn't directly equals, but has a larger range?

thanks again

Comment: Edited. You can set `platformWidth` and `platformHeight` to whatever you want. If each platform can have a different size, this won't be a good solution though

Comment: Thank you very much again!, have only just been able to get round to testing this but it works perfectly and it's no longer overlapping ! i am extremely grateful for all your help!